# A perfect finite dimensional Lie algebra with nontrivial center

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, homological-algebra

$\renewcommand{\g}{{\mathfrak g}}
$ We say that a Lie algebra $\g$  is *perfect* if $[\g,\g]=\g$.

> **Question.** Does there exist a finite dimensional, perfect Lie algebra $\g$ over $\Bbb C$ with nontrivial center?

If the answer is "Yes", I would like to see a nice example.

Comment: @CosmasZachos: The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is perfect (as any other semisimple Lie algebra). However, it has trivial center (only the matrix $0$).

Comment: Thanks... I just glossed over the nontrivial center bit.... [ugh...]

Comment: I believe that yes, these do exist. The paper "The structure of the invariants of perfect Lie algebras II" by Rutwig Campoamor-Stursberg seems to construct examples but unfortunately I don't have access to it to check.

Comment: @Callum: Indeed, this paper considers and maybe even classifies such examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $6$-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)\ltimes_{\phi} \mathfrak{n}_3(\Bbb C)$, which appears in the classification of all complex $6$-dimensional Lie algebras [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152952/complete-classification-of-six-dimensional-non-semi-simple-lie-algebra?rq=1) is perfect and has $1$-dimensional center. Here $\mathfrak{n}_3(\Bbb C)$ is the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra. It seems that this is also the example from the other answer. In fact, the other Lie algebras from the classification list in dimension $6$ are either not perfect, or have trivial center.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\SL{{\rm SL}}
\def\GL{{\rm GL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Der}{Der}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lie}{Lie}
\def\e{{\mathfrak e}}
\def\g{{\mathfrak g}}
\def\h{{\mathfrak h}}
\def\s{{\mathfrak s}}
\def\z{{\mathfrak z}}
\def\sl{{\mathfrak{sl}}}
\def\gl{{\mathfrak{gl}}}
$ The answer is Yes; see the example below.
See also the papers by  Rutwig Campoamor-Stursberg: [The structure of the invariants of perfect Lie algebras. J. Phys. A 36 (2003), no. 24, 6709–6723](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/36/24/309) and
[The structure of the invariants of perfect Lie algebras. II. J. Phys. A 37 (2004), no. 11, 3627–3643](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/37/11/007)
(thanks to @Callum for the reference).

**Derivations.** Let $k$ be a field, and $\g$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $k$.
A *derivation* of $\g$  is a linear map $\delta\colon \g\to \g$
such that
$$\delta\big([x,y]\big)=[\delta(x),y] + [x,\delta(y)]\quad\ \text{for all}\ \, x,y \in\g.$$
The derivations of $\g$ form a vector space $\Der\g$, which is a Lie subalgebra of $\gl(\g)$.
Consider the automorphism  group $\Aut\g$, which is a linear algebraic group, an algebraic subgroup of $\GL(\g)$.
Then $\Der\g=\Lie(\Aut\g)$;
see [this answer of Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1589323).

**Semi-direct sum of Lie algebras.**
Let $\g$ and $\h$ be Lie algebras, and let $\phi\colon \g\to\Der\h$ be a homomorphism.
Following  [Wikipedia: Lie algebra extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_extension),
we construct a
*semi-direct sum* $\h\oplus_\phi \g$.
We construct a skew-symmetric bracket on the vector space  $\h\oplus\g$:
$$ \big[(h_1,g_1),\,(h_2,g_2)\big]=\big([h_1,h_2]+\phi_{g_1}(h_2)-\phi_{g_2}(h_1),\, [g_1,g_2]\big)$$
for  $h_1,h_2\in \h,\ g_1,g_2\in \g$.
We check the Jacobi identity. We calculate:
\begin{align*}
\big[\, [&(h_1,g_1),(h_2,g_2)],\, (h_3,g_3)\,\big]
    =\big([[h_1,h_2],h_3]+[\phi_{g_1}(h_2),h_3]-[\phi_{g_2}(h_1),h_3]\\
& +\phi_{[g_1,g_2]}(h_3)-\phi_{g_3}([h_1,h_2])-\phi_{g_3}(\phi_{g_1}(h_2))
    +\phi_{g_3}(\phi_{g_2}(h_1)),\, [[g_1,g_2],g_3]\big)\\
&=\big(\,[[h_1,h_2],h_3]+[\phi_{g_1}(h_2),h_3]-[\phi_{g_2}(h_1),h_3]+\phi_{g_1}(\phi_{g_2}(h_3))-\phi_{g_2}(\phi_{g_1}(h_3))\\
& -[\phi_{g_3}(h_1),h_2]+[\phi_{g_3}(h_2),h_1]-\phi_{g_3}(\phi_{g_1}(h_2))
    +\phi_{g_3}(\phi_{g_2}(h_1)),\, [[g_1,g_2],g_3]\,\big).
\end{align*}
Using the Jacobi identities for $\g$ and $\h$:
\begin{gather*}
[[h_1,h_2],h_3]+[[h_2,h_3],h_1] +[[h_3,h_1],h_2]=0,\\
[[g_1,g_2],g_3]+[[g_2,g_3],g_1] +[[g_3,g_1],g_2]=0,
\end{gather*}
we obtain
\begin{multline*} \big[\, [(h_1,g_1),(h_2,g_2)],\, (h_3,g_3)\,\big]+
\big[\, [(h_2,g_2),(h_3,g_3)],\, (h_1,g_1)\,\big]\\
+\big[\, [(h_3,g_3),(h_1,g_1)],\, (h_2,g_2)\,\big]=0
\end{multline*}
(all the terms cancel out), which gives the Jacobi identity for $\h\oplus_\phi\g$.

**Example 1.**
Let $k$ be a field, $V=k^2$, $W=k$, $\psi\colon V\to W$ the standard non-degenerate skew-symmetric bilinear form.

We set $\h=V\oplus W$ and define a skew-symmetric bracket
$$\h\times \h\to W\hookrightarrow \h,\quad\, \big[(v_1,w_1), (v_2,w_2)\big]=\big(0, \psi(v_1,v_2)\big).$$
We have $[\h,\h]=W$, whence $[[\h,\h],\h]=0$, and the Jacobi identity for $\h$ is trivially satisfied.
Thus $\h$ is a (two-step nilpotent) Lie algebra with center $W$.

Set $S=\SL_2$  and $\s={\rm Lie}(S)=\sl_2$.
The algebraic group $S$ acts on the vector space $V=k^2$, and it acts on the vector space $\h$ by
$$ s, (v,w)\mapsto (s(v), w)\quad\ \text{for}\ \,s\in S,\ v\in V,\ w\in W.$$
The action on $\h$ preserves the Lie bracket in $\h$, and so we obtain a homomorphism
$f\colon S\to \Aut \h$.
Differentiating, we obtain a homomorphism
$$\phi:=df\colon \s\to \Lie(\Aut\h)=\Der \h.$$
An easy calculation shows that
$$\phi_s(v,w)=(s(v),0)\quad\ \text{for}\ \, s\in \s,\ v\in V,\ w\in W.$$
As above, we define a Lie algebra
$$\g=\h\oplus_\phi\s$$
with the bracket
$$ \big[(v_1,w_1,s_1),(v_2,w_2,s_2)\big]=\big(s_1(v_2)-s_2(v_1),\, \psi(v_1,v_2),\, [s_1,s_2]\big).$$

> **Proposition.**
> The constructed $6$-dimensional Lie algebra $\g$ is perfect with one-dimensional  center $\z(\g)=W$.

*Proof.*
From the formula
$$\big[(0,0,s_1),(0,0,s_2)\big]=\big(0,0,[s_1,s_2]\big)$$ we see that $[\g,\g]\supseteq \s$.
From the formula
$$\big[(0,0,s_1),(v_2,0,0)\big]=\big( s_1(v_2),0,0\big)$$ we see that $[\g,\g]\supseteq V$.
From the formula
$$\big[(v_1,0,0),(v_2,0,0)\big]=\big(0,\psi(v_1,v_2),0\big)$$ we see that $[\g,\g]\supseteq W$.
Thus $[\g,\g]=\g$, that is, $\g$ is perfect.

From the formula
$$ \big[(v_1,w_1,s_1),(0,w_2,0)\big]=(0,\, 0,\, 0)$$
we see that   $W\subseteq\z(\g)$.

From the formula
$$\big[(0,0,s_1),(v_2,w_2,s_2)\big]=\big( s_1(v_2),0,[s_1,s_2]\big)$$
we see that the centralizer of $\s$ in $\g$ is $W$. Thus $\z(\g)\subseteq W$ and $\z(\g)=W$.

We conclude that  $\g$ is perfect and has  one-dimensional center $W$.

EDIT: A more genral example, containing the example of @Callum.

**Example 2.** Let $\s$ be a semisimple Lie algebra,
$V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $\s$ (maybe reducible)
admitting a nontrivial invariant skew-symmetric bilinear form $\psi\colon V\times V\to k$
and not containing the trivial representation in $k$ as a direct summand.
We set $W=k$ and define a structure of Lie algebra on $\h:=V\oplus W$ by
$$\big[(v_1,w_1),\,(v_2,w_2)\big]=\big(0,\psi(v_1,v_2)\big).$$
We define a homomorphism
$$\phi\colon\s\to\Der\h,\quad\ \phi_s(v,w)=(s(v),0)
      \quad\ \text{for}\ \, s\in\s,\ v\in V,\ w\in W.$$
We check that $\phi_s$ is a derivation of $\h$.
The assumption that $\psi$ is $\s$-invariant means that
$$\psi(s(v_1), v_2)+\psi(v_1,s(v_2))=0\quad\ \text{for all}\ \, s\in\s,\ v_1,v_2\in V.$$
We calculate:
$$\phi_s\big[(v_1,w_1),\,(v_2,w_2)\big]=\phi_s\big(0,\psi(v_1,v_2)\big)=0.$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\big[\phi_s(v_1,w_1), (v_2,w_2)\big]+&\big[(v_1,w_1), \phi_s(v_2,w_2)\big]\\
=&\big[(s(v_1),0), (v_2,w_2)\big]+\big[(v_1,w_1), (s(v_2),0)\big]\\
=&\big(0,\,\psi(s_1(v_1),v_2)+\psi(v_1,s(v_2))\big)=0.
\end{align*}
Thus
$$\phi_s\big[(v_1,w_1),\,(v_2,w_2)\big] =\big[\phi_s(v_1,w_1), (v_2,w_2)\big]+\big[(v_1,w_1), \phi_s(v_2,w_2)\big],$$
as required.

We check that the linear map
$$ \phi\colon \s\to \Der\h,\quad\ s\mapsto\phi_s$$
is a homomorphism of Lie algebras.
Indeed,
$$\phi_{[s_1,s_2]}(v,w)=\big([s_1,s_2](v),0\big)=\big(s_1(s_2(v))-s_2(s_1(v)),\,0)\big).$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\phi_{s_1}(\phi_{s_2}(v,w))-\phi_{s_2}(\phi_{s_1}(v,w))=&\phi_{s_1}(s_2(v),0)-\phi_{s_2}(s_1(v),0)\\
=&\big(s_1(s_2(v)),\,0\big)-\big(s_2(s_1(v)),\,0\big).
\end{align*}
Thus
$$\phi_{[s_1,s_2]}(v,w)=\phi_{s_1}(\phi_{s_2}(v,w))-\phi_{s_2}(\phi_{s_1}(v,w)),$$
as required.

We set $\g=\h\oplus_\phi \s$. Arguing as in Example 1 and using the assumptions
that $\s$ is semisimple (hence perfect),
that the representation of $\s$ in $V$ does not contain the trivial representation
as a direct summand (whence $\big\langle s(v)\ |\ s\in S,\, v\in V\big\rangle=V\,$),
and that the skew-symmetric form $\psi$ is nontrivial
(whence $\big\{\psi(v_1,v_2)\ |\  v_1,v_2\in V\big\}=k\,$),
we conclude that  $\g$ is perfect and has  one-dimensional center $W$.

Comment: In both examples, $\mathfrak{h}$ is $2$-step nilpotent with $1$-dimensional center, hence a Heisenberg Lie algebra, right? Is $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{n}_3$ possible for $\mathfrak{s}=\mathfrak{sl}_2$ in Example $2$? In Callum's answer it is not.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: In Example 2, I don't assume that the skew-symmetric form $\psi$ is non-degenerate, and so $\frak h$ is not necessarily a Heisenberg Lie algebra. I assume only that $\psi$ is nontrivial (not identically zero).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Yes, in Example 2  we take ${\frak s}=\frak{sl}_2$, and let $V$ be the standard 2-dimensional representation of $\frak{sl}_2$. It admits a nondegenerate invariant skew-symmetric form $\psi$, and then ${\frak h}={\frak n}_3$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice simple example:

Let $\frak{g}$ be a Lie algebra with Levi decomposition $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_2 \oplus \frak{n}$ where $\mathfrak{n} = V \oplus V^* \oplus Z$. Here $V$ is a non-trivial irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ representation and $Z =\langle z \rangle$ is a $1$-dimensional trivial representation.

Define a bracket on $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \times \frak{n}$ by these representations and one on $\mathfrak{n} \times \frak{n}$ such that $[v, f]:= v(f)z$ and all other brackets are $0$. Note this makes $\mathfrak{n}$ a Heisenberg Lie algebra.

Then $\frak{g}$ is perfect since $[\mathfrak{sl}_2,\mathfrak{sl}_2] = \mathfrak{sl}_2$, $[\mathfrak{sl}_2,\mathfrak{n}] = V \oplus V^*$, $[\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{n}] = Z$. Then $Z$ is the centre of $\frak{g}$.

Edit: Note this example is actually distinct from the others given here despite also being the semidirect product of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and a Heisenberg Lie algebra. This construction only gives Heisenberg Lie algebras $\mathfrak{n}_{2n+1}$ for $n>1$ (i.e. $V$ is non-trivial). If $V$ is trivial this produces a non-perfect Lie algebra: $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}] = \mathfrak{sl}_2 \oplus Z$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah yes I hadn't seen your answer before I posted mine. I think this works for higher dimension Heisenberg Lie algebras as well so we have $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_2 \ltimes \mathfrak{n}_{2n+1}(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: @DietrichBurde actually on reflection I think this only works for higher dimension Heisenberg Lie algebras (I should have said $V$ is non trivial) so I think this must be a distinct example (assuming I haven't made a mistake)